# How to get the table name in OrmLite

Tags: java, ormlite

In OrmLite the name of a table is either the name of the class it is based on or whatever is defined in `@DatabaseTable(tableName = "...")` annotating that class.

Is there a convenient way to get the **name of a table at runtime**? In my case I need the name of all tables when upgrading the database to recreate database triggers based on those tables.

I already checked http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableInfo.html but I don't understand what the ID is supposed to be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [`extractTableName`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/DatabaseTableConfig.html#extractTableName%28java.lang.Class%29) method from the `DatabaseTableConfig` class.

> Extract and return the table name for a class.

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name = DatabaseTableConfig.extractTableName(A.class);
        System.out.println(name); //TableA
    }
}
@DatabaseTable(tableName="TableA")
class A {}
```